# Function body as arguments to a method call

Tags: java, function, ssl

I was reading some ones program which creates a connection and sends a SOAP message. I came across a strange statement where a complete function including body is passed in a method parameter. Can any one please explain this ? Please note that this is a working code.

```
//Open up connection 
httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
   return true;
   }
 });
```

Comment: That's an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thanks chrylis, does it mean that the Object TRUE is passed as the parameter ?

Comment: No, a single-purpose class is instantiated and passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Anonymous Inner class.  You can read about it more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

Pretend that this code was written like this instead:

```
httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new MyHostnameVerifier());

// another class file

public class MyHostnameVerifier extends HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
   return true;
   }
 });
```

This code will have exactly the same functionality.  There are other little nuances to this that do not apply to your example, but you can read about them in the link if you're interested.